# findcontrol not working for dynamically generated HTMLselect

Tags: asp.net, html, html-select, code-behind, findcontrol

I generate **select control**(Q1DDL and Q2DDL) in the innerHTML of a div **divQ1AnswerDDLSub** in the pageload

The code is perfectly generated as desired.

However, the findControl of ASP.net is not able to find the generated HTMLSELECT control (Q1DDL and Q2DDL)from the .aspx page after I press the **SUBMIT Button**.

The runtime HTMLSelect control generation

```
                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }   
....
if (bool.Parse(questions[QNo-1].AnswerDropDownList.visibleDDl))
            {
                (FindControl("lblQ" + QNo + "AnswerDDL") as HtmlGenericControl).InnerText = questions[QNo-1].AnswerDropDownList.titleDDL;
                (FindControl("fsQ" + QNo + "DDL") as HtmlGenericControl).Style["border"] = questions[QNo - 1].AnswerDropDownList.FieldsetDDL == "no" ? "0px" : null;
                var licDDL = questions[QNo-1].AnswerDropDownList.optionDDL;
                var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < licDDL.Length; i++)
                    {
                        builder.Append(String.Format("<option value='{0}' title='{1}'  >{1}</option> ", licDDL[i].value, licDDL[i].text));

                    }
                if (questions[QNo-1].AnswerDropDownList.required == "yes")
                    {
                        (FindControl("divQ" + QNo + "AnswerDDLSub") as HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = "<select runat=\"server\" name=\"Q" + QNo + "DDL\" id=\"Q" + QNo + "DDL\" required=\"required\">" + builder.ToString() + "</select>";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        (FindControl("divQ" + QNo + "AnswerDDLSub") as HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = "<select runat=\"server\" name=\"Q" + QNo + "DDL\" id=\"Q" + QNo + "DDL\">" + builder.ToString() + "</select>";
                    }
             }
```

The generated code when i view the page source

```
<div id="divQ1AnswerDDL">
            <fieldset id="fsQ1DDL" style="border:;">
                <legend>
                    <label id="lblQ1AnswerDDL">Title of Drop Down List </label>
                </legend>
                <div id="divQ1AnswerDDLSub"><select runat="server" name="Q1DDL" id="Q1DDL" required="required"><option value='' title='Select'  >Select</option> <option value='IE' title='IE'  >IE</option> <option value='Safari' title='Safari'  >Safari</option> <option value='Chrome' title='Chrome'  >Chrome</option> </select></div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

in the code behind

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
....
for (int QNo = 1; QNo < questions.Length + 1; QNo++)
        {
          ADDLRequired = (FindControl("Q" + QNo + "DDL") as     HtmlSelect).Attributes["required"] == "required" ? true: false,


}
}
```

**(FindControl("Q" + QNo + "DDL") as HtmlSelect)** <== is showing null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets start with the mistake that you render this

`<select runat="server" name="Q1DDL" id="Q1DDL" required="required"><option`

**as string inside HTML page**, and the mistake is that you expect that this will be compile. No actually this is not compile - the compile is happens before, after the compile this will be render as text - and not more compiles are happens.

So stick on this as first step... solve that, and then solve the rest issues.

### Possible work out

Render what ever html normal control you like, with out the `runat="server"`, then render it again after post back and get the post back using the `Request.Form["ControlName"]` to get the post back value

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake. Can you tell me how to render it again? If I remove the IsPostback Check from the Page_Load, the render occur again on submit button click but the problem still exist

Comment: @shomaail You need to understand what you do there. This is not dynamic render of controls, is just text - so as text just render normal controls.

Comment: I would be grateful if you give me an example to render control from code behind

Comment: @shomaail If I find some free time, I will do